# Who Wrote the 1981 Introduction to The Book of Mormon?

Tags: lds, book-of-mormon

I know that the general answer to this question can be found easily. It was added to the Book in 1981, which is when Spencer W Kimball was the president of the Church. So it could probably be said that it was written under his direction - or something like that. However, I'm interested in more information than that. Also, although he did write at least [one book I can think of](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miracle_of_Forgiveness), at that time [President Kimball was having health problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_W._Kimball) which seem to me may have stopped him from doing much more than just approving writing work.

I'm wondering if there's any specific information about who wrote [the Introduction](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm/introduction?lang=eng), who supervised the writing of it, or anything like that - or if it was just anonymously produced "by The Church".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog](https://juvenileinstructor.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/change-in-book-of-mormon-introduction/) says that Bruce R McConkie wrote it, but there is no source to back that up

This Oct 1981 Ensign [article](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1981/10/the-church-publishes-a-new-triple-combination?lang=eng) published about the new edition to the Book of Mormon says:

> As always, inspired direction came from the Scriptures Publication Committee of the Quorum of the Twelve: Elder Thomas S. Monson, chairman, Elder Boyd K. Packer, and Elder Bruce R. McConkie, with Brother W. James Mortimer serving as executive secretary.

So it is possible that Bruce R McConkie wrote it but it could've been someone else or a collaborative effort.

I believe the best you'll find is that it was written 'by The Church'

Comment: Thanks @depperm. That blog is great - I wish it referenced that comment!! I haven't poured a ton of time into digging any deeper into this, but I'm starting to think you might be right that it's just written 'by the Church'. I'm just going to upvote your answer for now. Let's see if I can find any other information.